# Bridge Objective-C to Swift - can't see file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, nsstring

I am writing an app for Apple Watch and I want to include `Constants.h` used in corresponding iPhone app (written in ObjC) into the watch app (swift).
I've tried Apple tutorial for that (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), but the bridging file doesn't see the actual header file.

Probably the error is caused by the fact, that watch extension is separate target, but where and how should I specify the files to be included?

What's more, when including constants.h in the bridge file, all the constants are showing editor errors:

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` is part of Foundation.  The compiler is complaining that it can't resolve that type. Add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to the top of your header.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.  I've added foundation also to be included in bridging file, not in the constants.h